# Why I’m getting an `AccessDenied` when trying to upload to my S3 bucket with `PutObject` permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

Any idea why I’m getting an `AccessDenied` error when trying to upload to my S3 bucket?

`serverless.yml`:

```
service: foo-service

custom:
  bucket: my-bucket-name

provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*"

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    environment:
      BUCKET: ${self:custom.bucket}
```

I'm trying to add a file to S3 with `public-read` permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s3:PutObject` permission alone allows you to add an item to the S3 bucket, but if you configure any ACL attributes you'll need the additional permission `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

It should be like this:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:PutObject
        - s3:PutObjectAcl
      Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*"
```